# Aurelia Animation Not Kicking In

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to get some simple animiation to work with Aurelia;

First, I have the plug-in in main:

```
.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-animator-css'))
```

Then I define some css for the animation:

```
.my-cool-element > .au-enter {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}

.my-cool-element > .au-enter-active {
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 5s;
    animation: fadeIn 5s;
}

.my-cool-element > .au-leave-active {
    -webkit-animation: fadeOut 5s;
    animation: fadeOut 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Then I use it in the html:

```
<div class="my-cool-element">
  <div class="au-animate">
    <div if.bind="showMessage"  class="navbar">${message}</div>
   </div>  
</div>
```

Then in code, I set showMessage=true and the element shows with the message, but it does not animiate.

But it doesn't animate.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the animation plug-in is mostly for animating routing

Comment: I am pretty sure I remember the skeleton doing fade-in's on the git-hub users page, as well as the routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out for the animation to work with `if.bind`, the `au-animate` class needs to be in the same element, like this:

```
<div  class="my-cool-element">
  <div if.bind="showMessage" class="au-animate">
    <div class="navbar">${message}</div>
</div>
```